# Total file size with subfolders

Tags: c#, file, size

What's the best way to iterate folders and subfolders to get total size of each folder starting at a specified location?

A small sample:

C:/,D:/,F:/games,G:/bla/bla/bla,

I want a methode that checks he size of the root directory..
So something like this:

C:/ totalsize = 1000GB, D:/ total size = 1000GB, F:/games total size of F:/ = 1000GB, G:/bla/bla/bla ,total size of G:/ = 1000GB

```
foreach (string directory in drives)
        {
            if (directory == GoPro1 || directory == GoPro2 || directory == GoPro3 || directory == GoPro4)
            {
                //gets drive letter from directory location
                var drive = Path.GetPathRoot(directory);

                //create new drive info
                DriveInfo di = new DriveInfo(drive);

                verbruik[teller1] = ("Total Size " + di.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 + " GB " + "Free Space " + di.AvailableFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 + "GB" + "       Total Sub dir: " + drive);
                teller1 = teller1 + 1;
            }

        }
```

This is what i have but this won't show me the total size of the selected subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static long GetFolderSize(string directory)
{
    return new DirectoryInfo(directory).GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Sum(file => file.Length);
}
```